# Skip back button in MediaElementJs?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

Is there a skip back button (say 10 seconds) for the MediaElementJs player?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "skip back" button but check this in case it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/28226534/1055987

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more descriptive. What I want is a button in the player that when pressed goes back say 10 seconds from the current point the video is playing and then start playing from that time. I know how to do this outside of the player.

Comment: I don't think that option exist "out-of-the-box", these are your options `features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'],`